# How do I make the built-in password_reset view use django-mailer?

Tags: python, django, django-registration, django-mailer

I'm using [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) on my web app.
I also already use django-mailer to send a few notification emails.

Django registration enables the builtin password reset feature ([here](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/registration/auth_urls.py)), by delegating the resetting logic to **django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset**.

Now that function doesn't know about django-mailer. How can I make it use django-mailer? Do I have to replicate the password_reset code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh that was easy.

I just had to set

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'mailer.backend.DbBackend'
```

in the settings file, like [this](https://github.com/freedomsponsors/www.freedomsponsors.org/blob/master/djangoproject/frespo/settings.py)

Now, "normal" send_mail calls will behave like mailer.send_mail and store the email to the database.
So there's no need to replace the calls themselves.